# Group unique elements within a time interval in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have some data as such:

```
User Date        
001  1/1/2000     
002  1/25/2000    
003  2/2/2005     
004  2/5/2005     
005  12/24/2008
```

I would like to find out, in each month, how many unique users are present?

So in my case, there would be 2 users present for Jan 2000, 2 users for Feb 2005, and 1 user for Dec 2008.

Towards solving this, I have tried using a PivotTable, however, I can't find the appropriate way to group the data by month. So I suspect I need to use the equation bar, but I'm not sure how to use a Group By function.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? I'm using Excel 2010. I could achieve your requirement just by applying filter to the data

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the top rows of the data (say username and date row) and apply filter to your data as shown below.
[image: Applying filter]
Then after you have applied filter your data will appear like this.
[image: Filter applied]

Now click on the drop down arrow on the date column and it will give you the options to select year and month wise as shown below
[image: Filter selection]

*Edit 1:*

Make a copy of your file in the first place. Further, if you want to remove the duplicates of the user column and count, in Excel, Select **Data** tab and  within **Data tools** group click on ***Remove duplicates***. Uncheck the remaining columns and keep only "USER" and click OK. [image: Remove duplicates]
This action will delete the duplicate records found in USER column. Now you have only unique records. You can do a pivot table and find out the count.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your data: `=YEAR(<date cell>) & MONTH(<date cell>)`. Then try the pivot table.

Alternatively, format the date column using the cell properties as a custom format:     'yyyy-mm'. And then pivot the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column and use this equation to unify days in a month:

```
=[DATECELL]-DAY([DATE_CELL])+1
```

Then apply a PivotTable to this column.